# Nginx doesn't work with ASPNET Core 6 & Angular | Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c#, angular, ubuntu, nginx, deployment

I'm trying to warm up asp.net an application with Angular on Ubuntu 20.04, while using Nginx.
It seems like everything that needs to be installed, configured, but still gives an error when entering the address.
My configs:

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

/* Adding db contexts */

var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    //app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;

app.Run();
```

It seems like there should be an HTTP connection between Nginx and ASP NET, but the user and Nginx can have HTTPS. For this reason, I commented out the lines concerning HSTS and HTTPSRedirection.

nginx/sites-enabled/domain.ru

```
server {
    server_name domain.ru www.domain.ru;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = domain.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    if ($host = www.domain.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server_name domain.ru www.domain.ru;
    listen        80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 404;
}
```

Here I tried to change the port in every possible way. The daemon status says that the application is running on port 5000, but then on request https://domain.ru 404 will return, if you change the port to any other (5001, 7163), then the 502 Bad Gateway error will be returned.

I demonize the application with the service:
/etc/systemd/system/daemon.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Example .NET Web API App running on Linux

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/ASPsite/ASPsite/bin/Debug/net6.0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/ASPsite/ASPsite/bin/Debug/net6.0/ASPsite.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=www-data
#envs
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

With all this, if I enter the IP address of the server in the search, then the Nginx start page will return to HTTP, and the HTTPS 404.
I have already tried opening the port in ufw 5000 and 5001, it didn't seem to help.

Open 5000 & 5001 ports, change ports in location in nginx config file, update Program.cs with configure HTTP connection between Nginx and ASPNET